# # of Impressions is low comparing to # of Filled on Facebook Audience Network

Tags: android, facebook, ads, facebook-audience-network

In our app, we have a feed of images loaded in an ListView. These images are returned from our server. When an user scrolls down to the bottom of the page, a load-more logic would be triggered, where we will send another request to our server to ask for more content (images) to display. This is also the time when we request for one FAN ads using the Facebook SDK. If an ad is indeed returned by Facebook, we will insert it into the list of content just returned by our server. Finally, when this cell (containing the FAN ad) is in view, we would start loading the content (images and texts) of this cell.

Given we don't pre-cache FAN ad, we expect the # of Impression to # of Filled ratio to be close to 100%. However, we've been observing a ratio of around 67%.

FYI - all FAN ads referenced here are NativeAd.

Question: what happened to the 33% of the Filled requests? Somehow they are rendered, but are not counted as Impressions?

Comment: How is the ad being delivered into the App - Native Ad View?

Comment: @MorrisonChang That is correct, I also load the image with NativeAd.downloadAndDisplayImage

Answer (score 4):

I am an engineer working on Audience Network. Impression for a NativeAd is logged only when the view registered for that NativeAd is viewable on screen. If the view is in the part of the list view that is not yet visible on screen, it will not be counted as an impression. (It will be counted when it becomes visible.) This should explain the difference between filled requests and impressions.

Comment: This makes sense. I think the # of Impression to # of Filled ratio is positively correlated to RPM. With that, how can one optimize this ratio? Reducing the page size would certainly help, however, that may not be an option from an UX perspective. I can't imagine loading FAN ads synchronously (only request when the designated cell is in view) for performance reasons. Any other ideas/suggestions?

Comment: There will be new utility classes coming out to help with such use case. Stay tuned!

Comment: @ethangui Check out NativeAdsManager which helps with loading and caching of multiple native ads. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios/nativeadsmanager

Comment: thanks for the update. FBNativeAdsManager seems to provide several utility methods to pre-cache and auto-refresh FAN native ads. However, I don't seem to see any features that could help to improve the Fill to Impression rate. i.e. if FBNativeAdsManager loads 10 ads, and we were only able to show 1, the Fill to Impression rate would be 10%, correct?

Comment: You don't need to optimize the fill to impression ratio. As long as you use the ads returned by NativeAdsManager in order, you will always get the most valuable ads first.

Comment: Are ads returned by FBNativeAdsManager "superior" than the ads returned via [nativeAd loadAd]? Since we didn't have access to FBNativeAdsManager before, we put together some utility functions that handles the pre-caching and refreshing of the native ads. Additionally, based on our observation, we found a positive correlation between the Fill to Impression rate and the RPM, thus we were wondering how we could optimize such ratio.

Comment: @SongQian I have noticed that the impression is counted a bit later then it is showed i.e. some seconds. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer I've worked on a Ad SDK.

The Ad View is a WebView and there are a few ways to know that an ad has been loaded.

1) Wait for a Javascript call back from the Ad to the SDK who will then fire a tracking pixel/request to make sure that ad is really VISIBLE (vs HIDDEN/INVISIBLE) before counting

and/or

2) Fire a tracking pixel/request from the WebView.

Either way as it is a WebView, even though the image has loaded, it doesn't necessarily mean that the load completed state has been communicated - especially if the Ad is within in a fast scrolling ListView where the image for the ad might be visible, but the rest of the Javascript code hasn't quite reached the 'Ad done loading' state. Basically an Ad is a small HTML5/CSS/Javascript bundle and subject to the delays therein - which could be on the order of seconds.

One way to check is to monitor the traffic via HTTP Proxy and take a best guess as to when it fires and adjust expectations.

Alternatively is to move the Ad to a footer/header where it isn't subject to the visible/loading problem if it within the scroll part of a ListView.

Comment: Hi Morrison, I think @Shing mentioned that it is a NativeAd, therefore no WebView and tracking pixel are used.

Comment: More about FAN Native Ads: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/native-api

Comment: @ethangui Perhaps, then the delay may be due to the SDK verifying that an AdView is visible i.e. the ad doesn't count unless visible for a full second. A session with an HTTP proxy can provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that if you want to track the actual impression you can implement the `ImpressionListener` that fires the `onLoggingImpression(Ad)`, called immediately before an impression is logged.See docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/interface/ImpressionListener/).

There is a full implementation of facebook native ads in the MoPub nativeads custom native event [here](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/blob/master/extras/src/com/mopub/nativeads/FacebookNative.java):

that clearly shows you how to implement it in the right way.